# ArcGIS Arcade Expression to combine multiple layers for use in a serial chart

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am trying to go about combining multiple layers in an dashboard arcade expression for a serial dashboard.
I have two layers and I want to use a field from each layer.

```
var portal = Portal('https://www.arcgis.com');
var fs = FeatureSetByPortalItem(portal,'<ItemID>',0,['*'],false);
var fs2 = FeatureSetByPortalItem(portal,'<itemID',0,['*'],false);

var together = [fs, fs2];

return Concatenate(together)
```

If I execute a 'return fs' or 'return fs2' it will pull up the table for each layer. But what I want is to be able to use both layers in the chart as a data source. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: The [Concatenate()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#concatenate) function combines text, you are providing a list of featuresets which makes no sense.